# In several selects make selected options uniq

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have question where you need to find pairs of words in Russian and English

```
<div class="form-group" id="question4">
  <label for="q4FirstSelectEN">4</label>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-lg-offset-2 col-lg-2 q4EN">
        <select name="firstSelectEn" id="q4FirstSelectEN">
          <option disabled selected style="display: none" value=""></option>
          <option value="red">red</option>
          <option value="green">green</option>
          <option value="purple">purple</option>
        </select>
        <select class="top-buffer" name="secondSelectEn" id="q4SecondSelectEN">
          <option disabled selected style="display: none" value=""></option>
          <option value="red">red</option>
          <option value="green">green</option>
          <option value="purple">purple</option>
        </select>
        <select class="top-buffer" name="secondSelectEn" id="q4ThirdSelectEN">
          <option disabled selected style="display: none" value=""></option>
          <option value="red">red</option>
          <option value="green">green</option>
          <option value="purple">purple</option>
        </select>
      </div>
      <div class="col-lg-2 q4RU">
        <select name="firstSelectRu" id="q4FirstSelectRu">
          <option disabled selected style="display: none" value=""></option>
          <option value="red">красный</option>
          <option value="green">зелёный</option>
          <option value="purple">фиолетовый</option>
        </select>
        <select  class="top-buffer" name="firstSelectRu" id="q4SecondSelectRu">
          <option disabled selected style="display: none" value=""></option>
          <option value="red">красный</option>
          <option value="green">зелёный</option>
          <option value="purple">фиолетовый</option>
        </select>
        <select  class="top-buffer" name="firstSelectRu" id="q4ThirdSelectRU">
          <option disabled selected style="display: none" value=""></option>
          <option value="red">красный</option>
          <option value="green">зелёный</option>
          <option value="purple">фиолетовый</option>
        </select>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

When user selects for example 'red' in (select) inside (div class='q4EN')  in all remaining selects in this (div class=q4EN) selected 'red' option become nonSelectable

*(nonSelectable is class in css with display:none)*

When user change decision and select 'green' instead of 'red' in first (select) red became available in rest selects and green become nonSelectable

When all 3 select have their value user can't change anything

My js for this is not working and I out of ideas

```
$(".q4EN").find("select").change(function () {
    $(".q4EN").find("select")
    .not(this)
    .find("option:selected")
    .addClass("nonSelectable");
});
```

Comment: and for this selects I want when user selects for example 'red' in .q4EN block in all remaining selects in this block this selected option become nonSelectable (nonSelectable is class in css with display:none) and whe user change decision and select 'green' instead of 'red' red became available and green nonSelectable???

Comment: @void I want that all 3 selects working with different values at a time

Comment: Can you please elaborate and simplify your problem statement in OP.

Comment: Did any of the answer below solves your problem?

Comment: @void I selected the answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an alternate way to achieve what you need. It basically iterate through every select element and find the corresponding option and disables it.

```
$('select').find("option").addClass("selectable");

$('select').on("change",function()
{
   // $(this).find("option").prop("disabled",false); // uncomment this if you wish to reset the disabled selection
    var $thisId = this.id;
    var $selectedOption = $(this).find("option:selected").val();
    $('select').each(function()
    {
        if(this.id !== $thisId)
        {
          //  $(this).find("option").removeClass("non-selectable").addClass("selectable"); // uncomment this if you wish to reset the disabled selection
            $(this).find("option[value=" + $selectedOption + "]").prop("disabled",true).addClass("non-selectable").removeClass("selectable");

        }
    });    
})
```

https://fiddle.jshell.net/a2n234eq/4/

To target a specific group ( like EN and RU ) , change `$('select')` to `$('.q4EN select')`

Comment: in fiddle I can select red then green and again red, but all 3 must be different at a time, so if red and green selected only purple remains

Comment: Updated the code to reflect the necessary changes. Follow the comments

Answer (score 2):

I believe the problem is order of operations.

```
$(".q4EN").find("select").change(function () {
    $(".q4EN").find("select")   //Finds all select lists
    .not(this)                  //Finds all except the one just changed
    .find("option:selected")    //Finds selected of all except the one just changed
    .addClass("nonSelectable"); //Wont do anything because nothing was selected
});
```

Try the following:

```
    $(".q4EN").find("select").change(function() {UpdateOptions();});

    function UpdateOptions(){
        var ss = $(".q4EN").find("select");
        ss.find('option').prop("disabled", false); //Enable all before disabling selected
        ss.each(function () {
            var s = $(this).val();
            if(s != undefined && s != "") {
                ss.find("option[value=" + s + "]").prop("disabled", true);
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: this is my mistake)

but it works then only on second change and remove option only in previously select, I think it is because selected items on first change is empty selection

Comment: It works but when user change decision he can't select all 3 colors

for example if I select in first select red then change to green and then for purple, in the rest 2 then I can't select anything

Comment: This almost works but if I chose in first select and in third, then in second I can select 2 values instead of one (see on fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/0rafnb37/1/)

Comment: Odd, logically it should work just fine. @DinoMyte's solution doesn't work for me. If you select all of the ones in the first row, nothing is enabled in the others.